# Naranath Bhranthan, earliest mentions and sources?

Tags: india, reference-request

**Naranath Bhranthan** appears to be a figure from medieval Indian tradition, but except for some repeats of [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naranath_Bhranthan)  I have not been able to find anything worth commenting. When and where do the stories about him start? A resemblance with [Sysiphus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus) is currently noted but is there some elaboration on it? 
One can guess also about some astronomical connection as he is the son of an astrologer and his story hints at a cyclicity and time (i.e. kala or Kali or Death). Any suggestions about related writings would be appreciated.